# Нужен скрипт слайдера с кнопками, работающем внутри скрипта увеличивающего изображение (simplebox)

Tags: javascript

**Ниже скрипт который увеличивает изображение при нажатии на него.**
Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы кнопки (которые вписал в скрипт) < > переключали изображения связанные с тем, которое открыто в данный момент(на странице много изображений). То есть, я нажимаю на изображение, оно увеличилось, там кнопки <> при нажатии на которые скрипт будет менять значение img src="image1" на src="image2" и т.д. Скрипт слайдера есть ниже под комментом //---, отдельно работает почти как надо.

```js
var simplebox = (function() {
  var _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9 = null,
    _a = false,
    _b, _c, _d, _e, _f, _10 = 1,
    _11 = 20,
    _12 = new Image,
    fx = {
      style: {}
    },
    _13, _14, _15, _16 = /\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)(.*)?$/i,
    _17 = /[^\.]\.(swf)\s*$/i,
    _18, _19 = [],
    _1a = {
      padding: 10,
      margin: 20,
      width: 560,
      height: 340,
      cyclic: false,
      overlayShow: true,
      hideOnOverlayClick: true,
      hideOnContentClick: false,
      swf: {
        wmode: "opaque"
      },
      h5video: {
        controls: "controls",
        preload: "metadata",
        autoplay: false
      },
      flashPlayer: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf",
      titlePosition: "inside",
      titleShow: true,
      titleFormat: null,
      transitionIn: "fade",
      transitionOut: "fade",
      speedIn: 500,
      speedOut: 500,
      changeSpeed: 500,
      changeFade: 500,
      scrolling: "auto",
      autoScale: true,
      autoDimension: true,
      enableCenter: true,
      enableMouseWheel: true,
      showCloseButton: true,
      showNavArrows: true,
      enableEscapeButton: true,
      overlayColor: "#666",
      overlayOpacity: "0.3",
      preloadIndent: 1
    };

  function _1b() {
    _5.style.display = "none";
    _12.onerror = _12.onload = null;
  };

  function _1c() {
    if (_a) {
      return;
    }
    _a = true;
    _1b();
    _a = false;
  };

  function _1d() {
    simplebox.start({
      content: "Sorry! the request cann't be reached"
    }, {
      transitionIn: "none",
      transitionOut: "none"
    });
  };

  function _1e() {
    var _1f = function() {
        _4.innerHTML = _2.innerHTML = "";
        Box.fadeOut(_1, "fast", function() {
          _a = false;
        });
      },
      t;
    if (_a) {
      return;
    }
    _a = true;
    _1b();
    Box.removeEvent(document, "keydown", _54);
    Box.removeEvent(window, "resize", _3e);
    _6.style.display = "none";
    _7.style.display = "block"; // кнопка <
    _8.style.display = "block"; // кнопка >
    _4.style.overflow = "hidden";
    if (_9) {
      _9.parentNode.removeChild(_9);
      _9 = null;
    }
    if (_e.transitionOut == "fade") {
      Box.fadeOut(_3, _1f);
    } else {
      if (_e.transitionOut == "elastic") {
        t = _14;
        _14 = _13;
        _13 = t;
        new Animate(fx, "fx", {
          from: 0,
          to: 1,
          step: _3a,
          time: _e.speedOut,
          callback: function() {
            _3.style.display = "none";
            _1f();
          }
        });
      } else {
        _3.style.display = "none";
        _1f();
      }
    }
  };

  function _20() {
    var d = document.createDocumentFragment(),
      t = Box.createElement("div", {
        "id": "simplebox"
      });
    d.appendChild(t);
    _2 = Box.createElement("div", {
      "id": "simple-tmp"
    });
    t.appendChild(_2);
    _5 = _2.cloneNode(false);
    _5.id = "simple-loading";
    _5.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    t.appendChild(_5);
    _1 = _2.cloneNode(false);
    _1.id = "simple-overlay";
    t.appendChild(_1);
    _3 = _2.cloneNode(false);
    _3.id = "simple-outer";
    t.appendChild(_3);
    _4 = _2.cloneNode(false);
    _4.id = "simple-inner";
    _3.appendChild(_4);
    _6 = Box.createElement("a", {
      "id": "simple-close"
    });
    _3.appendChild(_6);
    _7 = Box.createElement("a", {
      "id": "simple-left"
    });
    _7.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:chgImg(-1)'); //атрибут для слайдера <
    var _21 = Box.createElement("span", {
      "id": "simple-left-ico",
      "className": "simple-ico"
    });
    _7.appendChild(_21);
    _3.appendChild(_7);
    _8 = Box.createElement("a", {
      "id": "simple-right"
    });
    _8.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:chgImg(1)'); //атрибут для слайдера >
    var _21 = Box.createElement("span", {
      "id": "simple-right-ico",
      "className": "simple-ico"
    });
    _8.appendChild(_21);
    _3.appendChild(_8);
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    Box.addEvent(_6, "click", _1e);
    Box.addEvent(_7, "click", _22);
    Box.addEvent(_8, "click", _23);
    Box.addEvent(_5, "click", _1c);
  };
  //---------------------------------------------- скрипт слайдера
  slider = new Array("image.gif", "image2.gif");
  var ImgNum = 0;
  var ImgLength = slider.length - 1;

  function chgImg(direction) {
    if (document.images) {
      ImgNum = ImgNum + direction;
      if (ImgNum > ImgLength) {
        ImgNum = 0;
      }
      if (ImgNum < 0) {
        ImgNum = ImgLength;
      }
      document.slider.src = slider[ImgNum];
      if (document.layers) {}
    }
  }
  //----------------------------------------------
  function _24() {
    if (_a) {
      return;
    }
    _a = true;
    _1b();
    _e = Box.extend({}, _d);
    var obj = _b[_c],
      _25, _26, _27 = _e.orig,
      t, arr;
    typeof _27 == "string" && (_27 = document.querySelector(_27));
    obj.getElementsByTagName && !_27 && (_e.orig = _27 = obj.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]);
    _e.title = obj.title || (_27 && (_27.title || _27.alt)) || "";
    _25 = _e.href || obj.href || null;
    if (_e.type) {
      _26 = _e.type;
      if (_26 == "html") {
        _25 = _e.content;
      }
    } else {
      if (_25) {
        if (_25.match(_16)) {
          _26 = "image";
        } else {
          if (_25.match(_17)) {
            _26 = "swf";
          }
        }
      }
      if (typeof _e.content !== "undefined") {
        _26 = "html";
        _25 = _e.content;
      } else {
        if ((t = _e.video) && (arr = t.split(";")) && arr.length > 0) {
          var _28 = {
              mp4: "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2\"",
              webm: "video/webm; codecs=\"vp8, vorbis\"",
              ogv: "video/ogg; codecs=\"theora, vorbis\"",
              ogg: "video/ogg; codecs=\"theora, vorbis\""
            },
            swf = [],
            _29, _2a = null;
          _26 = "h5video";
          _29 = document.createElement("video");
          document.body.appendChild(_29);
          arr.forEach(function(el, _2b, arr) {
            var _2c = el.slice(-3),
              _2d;
            if (_2c != "flv" && (t = _28[_2c])) {
              if (_2c == "mp4") {
                swf.push(el);
                if (!_29.play) {
                  swf.push(el);
                  return;
                }
              }
              _2d = _29.canPlayType(t);
              if ((_2d == "probably" || _2d == "maybe") && !_2a) {
                _2a = "<source src=\"" + el + "\" type='" + t + "'>";
              }
            } else {
              swf.push(el);
            }
          });
          swf.length > 0 && (_25 = swf[0]);
          _2a && (_25 = _2a);
        }
      }
    }
    if (!_25 || !_26) {
      _a = false;
      return;
    }
    _e.href = _25;
    _e.type = _26;
    var str = "",
      emb = "",
      key, _2e;
    switch (_26) {
      case "image":
        _a = false;
        _5a();
        _12 = new Image();
        _12.onload = function() {
          _12.onerror = null;
          _12.onload = null;
          _2f();
        };
        _12.onerror = _1d;
        _12.src = _25;
        break;
      case "h5video":
        if (_29.play && _2a) {
          str += "<video id=\"simple-video\" ";
          for (key in _e.h5video) {
            str += key + "=" + _e.h5video[key] + " ";
          }
          str += "width=\"" + _e.width + "\" height=\"" + _e.height + "\">";
          str += _2a;
          str += "</video>";
          _2.innerHTML = str;
          document.body.removeChild(_29);
          _30();
          break;
        }
        if (swf.length > 0) {
          document.body.removeChild(_29);
          _e.swf["flashvars"] = _31();
          _e.href = _e.flashPlayer;
        }
      case "swf":
        str += "<object classid=\"clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000\" width=\"" + _e.width + "\" height=\"" + _e.height + "\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"" + _e.href + "\"></param>";
        for (key in _e.swf) {
          str += "<param name=\"" + key + "\" value='" + _e.swf[key] + "'></param>";
          emb += " " + key + "='" + _e.swf[key] + "'";
        }
        str += "<embed src=\"" + _e.href + "\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"" + _e.width + "\" height=\"" + _e.height + "\"" + emb + "></embed></object>";
        _2.innerHTML = str;
        _30();
        break;
      case "html":
        _2.innerHTML = _e.href;
        if (_e.autoDimension) {
          Box.extend(_2.style, {
            display: "block",
            position: "absolute"
          });
          _e.width = parseInt(Box.getComputedStyleValue(_2, "width"));
          _e.height = parseInt(Box.getComputedStyleValue(_2, "height"));
          Box.extend(_2.style, {
            display: "none",
            position: "auto"
          });
        }
        _30();
    }
  };

  function _31() {
    var _32 = {},
      t, p;
    p = _32["playlist"] = [];
    (t = _e["h5video"]["poster"]) && p.push(t);
    t = {};
    t.url = _e.href;
    t.autoPlay = _e.h5video.autoplay;
    t.autoBuffering = (_e.h5video.preload !== "none");
    p.push(t);
    return "config=" + JSON.stringify(_32);
  };

  function _2f() {
    _a = true;
    _2.innerHTML = "";
    _e.width = _12.width;
    _e.height = _12.height;
    _12.alt = _e.title;
    _12.name = "slide_metoyou"; //название слайдера
    _12.id = "simple-img";
    _2.appendChild(_12);
    _30();
  };

  function _30() {
    var w, h, _33, _34 = _e.fadeSpeed;
    _5.style.display = "none";
    _33 = Box.extend({}, _14);
    _14 = _35();
    _36();
    w = _14.width - 2 * _e.padding;
    h = _14.height - 2 * _e.padding - _15;
    if (Box.getComputedStyleValue(_3, "display") != "none") {
      _6.style.display = "none";
      _7.style.display = "none";
      _8.style.display = "none";
      Box.fadeOut(_4, _34, function() {
        _4.style.overflow = "hidden";
        _4.innerHTML = _2.innerHTML;
        _13 = {
          width: parseInt(_4.style.width),
          height: parseInt(_4.style.height),
        };
        if (_13.width == w && _13.height == h) {
          Box.fadeIn(_4, _34, function() {
            Box.extendStyle(_3, _14);
            _39();
          });
        } else {
          function _37(_38) {
            Box.fadeIn(_4, _34, _39);
          };
          _13 = _33;
          new Animate(fx, "fx", {
            from: 0,
            to: 1,
            time: _e.changeSpeed,
            step: _3a,
            callback: _37
          });
        }
      });
      return;
    }
    _13 = _3b();
    _4.innerHTML = _2.innerHTML;
    if (_e.overlayShow) {
      _1.style.backgroundColor = _e.overlayColor;
      _1.style.opacity = _e.overlayOpacity;
      _1.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (_e.transitionIn == "elastic") {
      Box.extend(_4.style, {
        top: _e.padding + "px",
        left: _e.padding + "px",
        width: Math.max(_13.width - (_e.padding * 2), 1) + "px",
        height: Math.max(_13.height - (_e.padding * 2), 1) + "px"
      });
      Box.extendStyle(_3, _13);
      _3.style.opacity = 1;
      _3.style.display = "block";
      new Animate(fx, "fx", {
        from: 0,
        to: 1,
        step: _3a,
        time: _e.speedIn,
        callback: _39
      });
    } else {
      Box.extendStyle(_3, _14);
      Box.extend(_4.style, {
        top: _e.padding + "px",
        left: _e.padding + "px",
        width: Math.max(_14.width - (_e.padding * 2), 1) + "px",
        height: Math.max(_14.height - (_e.padding * 2) - _15, 1) + "px"
      });
      if (_e.transitionIn == "fade") {
        Box.fadeIn(_3, _34, _39);
      } else {
        _3.style.opacity = 1;
        _3.style.display = "block";
        _39();
      }
    }
  };

  function _39() {
    var _3c = _e.scrolling;
    _3c = _3c == "auto" ? (_e.type == "html" ? "auto" : "hidden") : (_3c == "yes" ? "auto" : "visible");
    _4.style.overflow = _3c;
    if (_9) {
      _9.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (_e.showCloseButton) {
      _6.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (_e.hideOnContentClick) {
      Box.removeEvent(_4, "click", _1e);
      Box.addEvent(_4, "click", _1e);
    }
    if (_e.hideOnOverlayClick && _e.overlayShow) {
      Box.removeEvent(_1, "click", _1e);
      Box.addEvent(_1, "click", _1e);
    }
    _b.length > 1 && _3d();
    if (_e.enableCenter) {
      Box.addEvent(window, "resize", _3e);
    }
    _a = false;
    _3f();
  };

  function _3a(_40) {
    var _41 = Math.round(_13.width + (_14.width - _13.width) * _40),
      _42 = Math.round(_13.height + (_14.height - _13.height) * _40),
      top = Math.round(_13.top + (_14.top - _13.top) * _40),
      _43 = Math.round(_13.left + (_14.left - _13.left) * _40);
    Box.extendStyle(_3, {
      width: _41,
      height: _42,
      left: _43,
      top: top
    });
    _41 = Math.max(_41 - _e.padding * 2, 0);
    _42 = Math.max(_42 - (_e.padding * 2 + (_15 * _40)), 0);
    _4.style.width = _41 + "px";
    _4.style.height = _42 + "px";
  };

  function _44() {
    var de = document.documentElement;
    return {
      "width": (window.innerWidth || (de && de.clientWidth) || document.body.clientWidth),
      "height": (window.innerHeight || (de && de.clientHeight) || document.body.clientHeight)
    };
  };

  function _45() {
    var win = _44();
    return [win.width, win.height, document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft, document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop];
  };

  function _46(elm) {
    var h, w, t = 0,
      l = 0;
    h = elm.offsetHeight;
    w = elm.offsetWidth;
    do {
      l += elm.offsetLeft;
      t += elm.offsetTop;
    } while (elm = elm.offsetParent);
    return {
      width: w,
      height: h,
      left: l,
      top: t
    };
  };

  function _3b() {
    var _47 = _e.orig,
      _48 = {},
      pos, _49, p = _e.padding;
    if (_47) {
      pos = _46(_47);
      _48 = {
        width: (pos.width + (p * 2)),
        height: (pos.height + (p * 2)),
        top: (pos.top - p),
        left: (pos.left - p)
      };
    } else {
      _49 = _45();
      _48 = {
        width: 1,
        height: 1,
        top: _49[3] + _49[1] * 0.5,
        left: _49[2] + _49[0] * 0.5
      };
    }
    return _48;
  };

  function _35() {
    var _4a = _45(),
      to = {},
      _4b = _e.margin,
      _4c = _e.autoScale,
      _4d = _e.padding * 2,
      _4e = (_e.margin + _11) * 2,
      _4f = (_e.margin + _11) * 2;
    if (_e.width.toString().indexOf("%") > -1) {
      to.width = ((_4a[0] * parseFloat(_e.width)) / 100) - (2 * _11);
      _4c = false;
    } else {
      to.width = _e.width + _4d;
    }
    if (_e.height.toString().indexOf("%") > -1) {
      to.height = ((_4a[1] * parseFloat(_e.height)) / 100) - (2 * _11);
      _4c = false;
    } else {
      to.height = _e.height + _4d;
    }
    if (_4c && (to.width > (_4a[0] - _4e) || to.height > (_4a[1] - _4f))) {
      if (_e.type == "image") {
        _4e += _4d;
        _4f += _4d;
        var _50 = Math.min(Math.min(_4a[0] - _4e, _e.width) / _e.width, Math.min(_4a[1] - _4f, _e.height) / _e.height);
        to.width = Math.round(_50 * (to.width - _4d)) + _4d;
        to.height = Math.round(_50 * (to.height - _4d)) + _4d;
      } else {
        to.width = Math.min(to.width, (_4a[0] - _4e));
        to.height = Math.min(to.height, (_4a[1] - _4f));
      }
    }
    to.left = _4a[2] + (_4a[0] - to.width) * 0.5;
    to.top = _4a[3] + (_4a[1] - to.height) * 0.5;
    if (_e.autoScale == false) {
      to.top = Math.max(_4a[3] + _4b, to.top);
      to.left = Math.max(_4a[2] + _4b, to.left);
    }
    return to;
  };

  function _36() {
    var t = _e.title,
      w, p = _e.padding;
    if (_9) {
      _9.parentNode.removeChild(_9);
      _9 = null;
    }
    _15 = 0;
    if (!_e.titleShow) {
      return;
    }
    if (!t) {
      return;
    }
    t = typeof(_e.titleFormat) === "function" ? _e.titleFormat(t, _b, _c, _e) : _51(t);
    w = Math.max(_14.width - 2 * p, 1);
    _9 = Box.createElement("div", {
      "id": "simple-title",
      "innerHTML": t,
      "className": "simple-title-" + _e.titlePosition
    });
    Box.extend(_9.style, {
      width: w + "px",
      paddingLeft: p + "px",
      paddingRight: p + "px"
    });
    document.body.appendChild(_9);
    switch (_e.titlePosition) {
      case "over":
        _9.style.bottom = p + "px";
        break;
      default:
        _15 = _9.offsetHeight - _e.padding;
        _14.height += _15;
        break;
    }
    _3.appendChild(_9);
    _9.style.display = "none";
  };

  function _51(_52) {
    var ret = false;
    if (_52 && _52.length) {
      switch (_e.titlePosition) {
        case "over":
          ret = "<span id=\"simple-title-over\">" + _52 + "</span>";
          break;
        default:
          ret = _52;
          break;
      }
    }
    return ret;
  };

  function _3d() {
    var _53 = navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
    Box.addEvent(document, "keydown", _54);
    if (_e.enableMouseWheel) {
      Box.removeEvent(_3, _53, _55);
      Box.addEvent(_3, _53, _55);
    }
    if (!_e.showNavArrows) {
      return;
    }
    if ((_e.cyclic && _b.length > 1) || _c != 0) {
      _7.style.display = "block";
    }
    if ((_e.cyclic && _b.length > 1) || _c != (_b.length - 1)) {
      _8.style.display = "block";
    }
  };

  function _55(e) {
    var _56;
    e = e || window.event;
    _56 = e.wheelDelta ? (e.wheelDelta / 120) : (-e.detail / 3);
    _56 < 0 ? _23() : _22();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  function _3e() {
    console.log(_45());
    _13 = _3b();
    _14 = _35();
    if (_9) {
      _9.style.width = _14.width - 2 * _e.padding + "px";
      if (_e.titlePosition == "inside") {
        _15 = _9.offsetHeight - _e.padding;
        _14.height += _15;
      }
    }
    Box.extendStyle(_3, _14);
    Box.extend(_4.style, {
      top: _e.padding + "px",
      left: _e.padding + "px",
      width: Math.max(_14.width - (_e.padding * 2), 1) + "px",
      height: Math.max(_14.height - (_e.padding * 2) - _15, 1) + "px"
    });
  };

  function _54(e) {
    var _57 = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && _e.enableEscapeButton) {
      e.preventDefault();
      _1e();
    } else {
      if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _22();
      } else {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
          e.preventDefault();
          _23();
        }
      }
    }
  };

  function _22() {
    return pos(_c - 1);
  };

  function _23() {
    return pos(_c + 1);
  };

  function pos(pos) {
    if (_a) {
      return;
    }
    if (pos > -1 && _b.length > pos) {
      _c = pos;
      _24();
    }
    if (_e.cyclic && _b.length > 1 && pos < 0) {
      _c = _b.length - 1;
      _24();
    }
    if (_e.cyclic && _b.length > 1 && pos >= _b.length) {
      _c = 0;
      _24();
    }
  };

  function _58() {
    if (_5.style.display != "block") {
      clearInterval(_f);
      return;
    }
    _5.childNodes[0].style.top = (_10 * -40) + "px";
    _10 = (_10 + 1) % 12;
  };

  function _3f() {
    var i, l, t = _b.length,
      img, _59;
    for (i = _c + 1, l = _c + _e.preloadIndent; i <= l; ++i) {
      if (i > t - 1) {
        break;
      }
      _59 = _b[i].href;
      if (typeof _59 !== "undefined" && !_19[i] && _59.match(_16)) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = _b[i].href;
        _19[i] = img;
      }
    }
    for (i = l + 1; i < t - 1; ++i) {
      delete _19[i];
    }
    for (i = _c - 1, l = _c - _e.preloadIndent; i >= l; i--) {
      if (i < 0) {
        break;
      }
      _59 = _b[i].href;
      if (typeof _59 !== "undefined" && !_19[i] && _59.match(_16)) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = _b[i].href;
        _19[i] = img;
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
      delete _19[i];
    }
  };

  function _5a() {
    clearInterval(_f);
    _5.style.display = "block";
    _f = setInterval(_58, 66);
  };
  return {
    init: _20,
    start: function(el, _5b, now) {
      var _5c, _5d;
      if (typeof el === "string") {
        _5c = document.querySelectorAll(el);
        _5c = Array.prototype.slice.call(_5c, 0);
      } else {
        _5c = !Array.isArray(el) && [el];
      }
      if (arguments.length == 2 && typeof arguments[1] == "boolean") {
        now = _5b;
        _5b = null;
      }
      if (_5c.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      function go(_5e, _5f) {
        _b = _5f;
        _c = _5e;
        _d = Box.extend({}, _1a);
        var _60 = el.attributes,
          _61, t;
        if (_60) {
          for (var i = 0, l = _60.length; i < l; ++i) {
            _61 = _60[i].nodeName;
            if (_61.indexOf("data-") == 0) {
              _61 = _61.split("-");
              t = _61.pop();
              for (var j = 1, _62 = _61.length, _63 = _d; j < _62; ++j) {
                _63[_61[j]] && (_63 = _63[_61[j]]);
              }
              _63[t] = _60[i].nodeValue;
            }
          }
        }
        _5b && (Box.extend(_d, _5b));
        _d["width"] = parseInt(_d["width"]);
        _d["height"] = parseInt(_d["height"]);
        _24();
      };
      if (now) {
        el = _5c[0];
        go(0, _5c);
        return;
      }
      _5c.forEach(function(m, _64, arr) {
        Box.addEvent(m, "click", function(e) {
          el = m;
          e.preventDefault();
          go(_64, arr);
        });
      });
    }
  };
})();
```

```html
<a rel="simplebox" href="image.gif"><img src="image.gif"></a>
<script src="sbox/simplebox_util.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {
    var boxes = [],
      els, i, l;
    if (document.querySelectorAll) {
      els = document.querySelectorAll('a[rel=simplebox]');
      Box.getStyles('simplebox_css', 'sbox/simplebox.css');
      Box.getScripts('simplebox_js', 'sbox/simplebox.js', function() {
        simplebox.init();
        for (i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; ++i)
          simplebox.start(els[i]);
        simplebox.start('a[rel=simplebox_group]');
      });
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Пример работы скрипта: http://get-do-ok.ru/skript-uvelicheniya-kartinki-pri-nazhatii.html

Comment: Не правильно гуглил. Zoom with slider:
https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PortfolioZoomSlider/